# What is the meaning of an object param in a function signature?

Tags: typescript

What is the meaning of an object param in a function signature?  I came across this code snippet, and I'm not sure what's going on here.

```
export const items = (state: any = [], {type, payload}) => {
  case (type) {
    ...
  }
};
```

I don't understand the {type, payload} in the function signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of [destructuring](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html).

You can see what this:

```
let items = (state: any = [], {type, payload}) => {

};
```

compiles to on the TypeScript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20items%20%3D%20(state%3A%20any%20%3D%20%5B%5D%2C%20%7Btype%2C%20payload%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%3B):

```
var items = function (state, _a) {
     if (state === void 0) { state = []; }
     var type = _a.type, payload = _a.payload;
};
```

And from that I can infer that it means that the second parameter of the function will be an object with a property called "type", and another property called "payload". Further, I will be able to refer to "type" and "payload" directly in my function body:

```
let items = (state: any = [], {type, payload}) => {
    console.log(type);
    console.log(payload);
};

let myobj = {
    payload: "blue",
    type: "no-type"
}

items(null, myobj);
```

Comment: Just as an addendum, this is part of the ES6 spec and not something unique to TS.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @jthereliable Thanks!